# Keras convolution rank inconsistent with 1 filter

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Keras convolutions seem to be being too clever for my network - my final convolutional layer has 1 filter, and Keras seems to be squeezing the output shape to remove the filter axis. Unfortunately, it only does this at train time: `model.summary()` shows the filter axis where it should be.

I need to concatenate this output on the filter axis to another input, but if I trust the model summary I get a train time error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected leaky_re_lu_6 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 112, 112)`. Planting a `Reshape((1,112,112))` after the `LeakyReLU` doesn't help.

If I instead use `keras.backend.expand_dims(resized_output,1)` to force the size I want, I get a compile-time error: `ValueError: A 'Concatenate' layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 3, 448, 448), (None, 1, 1, 448, 448)]`

Relevant section of `model.summary()`:

```
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 1, 112, 112)
leaky_re_lu_6 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 1, 112, 112)              conv2d_6[0][0]
                                                                 conv2d_6[1][0]       
full_input (InputLayer)         (None, 3, 16, 448, 448)
lambda_1 (Lambda)               (None, 3, 448, 448)              full_input[0][0]
up_sampling2d_5 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 1, 448, 448)              leaky_re_lu_6[1][0]              
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 4, 448, 448)              lambda_1[0][0]                   
                                                                 up_sampling2d_5[0][0]
```

Model definition snippet:

```
data_format = "channels_first"

C3 = lambda filter_size: Conv3D(
        filter_size,
        (3, 3, 3),
        data_format=data_format,
        activation="relu",
        padding="same")
def P3(shape=(2, 2, 2)):
    return MaxPooling3D(
        shape,
        data_format=data_format)
C2 = lambda filter_size: Conv2D(
        filter_size,
        (3,3),
        data_format=data_format,
        padding="same")
U2 = lambda: UpSampling2D(data_format=data_format)

coarse_architecture = [
    # encoder                        #112, 16
    C3(64), P3(),                    #56 , 8
    C3(128), P3(),                   #28 , 4
    C3(256), C3(256), P3(),          #14 , 2
    C3(512), C3(512), P3(),          #7  , 1
    # decoder
    Reshape((512,7,7)),
    C2(256), LeakyReLU(0.001), U2(), #14
    C2(128), LeakyReLU(0.001), U2(), #28
    C2(64),  LeakyReLU(0.001), U2(), #56
    C2(32),  LeakyReLU(0.001), U2(), #112
    C2(16),  LeakyReLU(0.001),
    C2(1), LeakyReLU(0.001)
]

def coarse_inference(x):
    return apply_sequence(coarse_architecture, x)

# Siamese subnetwork
full_input    = Input(shape=(3,16,448,448),dtype='float32',name="full_input")
resized_input = Input(shape=(3,16,112,112),dtype='float32',name="resized_input")
cropped_input = Input(shape=(3,16,112,112),dtype='float32',name="cropped_input")
cropped_output = coarse_inference(cropped_input)



resized_output = coarse_inference(resized_input)

# Fine-tuning subnetwork
take_last_frame = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,-1,:,:],output_shape = (3,448,448))

last_frame = take_last_frame(full_input)
resized_output = UpSampling2D(size=(4,4),data_format=data_format)(resized_output)
fine_input = concatenate([last_frame,resized_output],axis=1)
fine_output = apply_sequence(fine_architecture, fine_input)

# Build model
model = Model(inputs=[full_input,cropped_input,resized_input],
              outputs=[cropped_output,fine_output])
```

Have I made a mistake specifying my model? How can I overcome this inconsistency?

Comment: There are important missing layers in your summary, especially the shape of `resized_output`.

Comment: The error message is about your "target" (y_train). It's not compatible with your model's output shape.

Comment: @DanielMöller the variable `resized_output` is assigned the output of   `leaky_re_lu_6`.

Comment: Something is quite wrong about the code you posted here. The error message clearly shows that Leaky Rely 6 is the final output of your model.

Comment: @DanielMöller Apologies, in the model definition I take both the output from that and another architecture to train against - I've added that to the code now to clarify. You're right that the error is regarding the `y_train`, I just completely misunderstood it. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the error message:

> ValueError: Error when checking **TARGET**: expected leaky_re_lu_6 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 112, 112)

We can see that the problem is that `y_train` (your training output data) is not compatible with the output shape of the model.

It seems that either `y_train` should have an extra dimension or the output of the model (said `leaky_re_lu_6`) should be worked to match your current `y_train`.

The details are only possible if we know your data better :)